# is this the right way to apply softmax?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, activation-function

```py
self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Flatten(),
        nn.Linear(in_features = 32*8*8, out_features = 26),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Linear(in_features = 26, out_features = output_shape),
        nn.Softmax(dim=1)
    )
```

and my loss fn is

```py
loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(params = model_0.parameters(),
                            lr = 0.07)
```

Is that the right way to use softmax? `output_shape` is equal to num of class (this is multi class classification)

If my implementation isn't wrong, then why do all of my data in 1 batch output the same class (even each data has very similar output probability)

[image]

Comment: yes your suppose to apply softmax after your final output because softmax maps the probabilities of your logits to [0- 1] range

Comment: @EdwinCheong I changed it, is it correct now?

Comment: yes but you might want to change your loss function l1 loss cross entropy internally applies softmax as well but since u added in inside your network, you have to change the loss https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.L1Loss.html

Comment: Hum, what as the L1 loss something to do with this?

Comment: @UrDailyCS, which loss function are you using during training?

Comment: @Ivan Im using cross Entropy Loss. I edited my question to add the loss fn

Answer (score 0):

No, `CrossEntropyLoss` doesn't require `Softmax` as it already includes it (or actually `LogSoftmax`): https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html?highlight=crossentropy#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.